# Match Escaped Dollar Sign in literal but not variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to determine if a value matches a string input by the user. When trying to match a dollar sign, I take the input string and replace the dollar sign with an escaped dollar sign ("\\$"). However, this doesn't match, but it will match if instead of assigning this value to a variable I just use the literal string. Here's a console snapshot illustrating this:

[image]

why is this happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how escaping works exactly, consider:

[image]

Your `b.toString() !== "\\$"`

Instead of `"$".replace("$", "\\\\$")` you want `"$".replace("$", "\\$")`

[image]

Comment: Ohh, because the string literal needed the double whack I thought `b` needed it too.